# Get Sticky User in user loop based on user role

Tags: loop, user-roles, users, wp-user-query

I have this shortcode to display a loop of user avatars with order by registration date.

```
function Profiles() {
    $args = array(
    'orderby' => 'registered',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
    );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { ?>

    <div class="user-item user-img-<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" rel="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $website; ?>" rel="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 100 ); ?></a>    
    </div>
    <?php }
    } else {
        echo 'No users found.';
    }
}
add_shortcode('profiles', 'Profiles');
```

If any user role changes to `sticky` (a custom role) then that users move to top of the list. Default orderby should stay as registered for all other users in the loop. Once `sticky` user role is removed, it goes back to normal sorting.

I gave it quite a bit thought and maybe if i can combine two arguments in a single `Wp_User_Query` that might do the trick?

For example `$sticky_args` have `role__in => 'sticky'` and `$simple_args` have all others `roles => 'subscriber', 'customer', 'author'` OR `role__not_in => 'sticky'` argument. Then combining this `Wp_User_Query` in a way that `$user_query->results` shows `$sticky_args` users list first and then `$simple_args` user list after that in the loop. I tried several codes and trying to think if statements but nothing works so far. Google didn't help either. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by adding 2 loops after each other. First loop display users with `'role__in' => 'sticky'` while second loop display users with `'role__not_in' => 'sticky'` It worked perfectly. Here is the code if it helps anyone.

```
function Profiles() {

    echo "<div class='users-list'>"

    // First loop with sticky users
    $args = array(
    'role__in' => 'sticky',
    'orderby' => 'registered',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
    );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { ?>

    <div class="user sticky-user user-img-<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" rel="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $website; ?>" rel="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 100 ); ?></a>    
    </div>
    <?php }
       }

    // Second loop without sticky users
    $args = array(
    'role__not_in' => 'sticky',
    'orderby' => 'registered',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
    );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { ?>

    <div class="user user-img-<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" rel="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $website; ?>" rel="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 100 ); ?></a>    
    </div>
    <?php }
    } else {
        echo 'No users found.';
    }

    echo "</div>"
}
add_shortcode('profiles', 'Profiles');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [read the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L0) (in version 4.5.2 on line 164-173) you will see that `orderby` can be an array of values, coupled with `order`. So you could modify `$args` like this:

```
     $args = array(
        'orderby' => array(
            array ('sticky' => 'DESC'),
            array ('registered' => 'DESC')),
        'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
        );
```

Note that I know nothing about how woocommerce defines the sticky user role, so I don't know if this code will actually work. It only shows how to implement a multidimensional array in the query.

Comment: I'm using 4.4.3.. Need update wordpress to test this, have some theme competbility issues, so i will try it on a new installation. Just a question, that sticky in `'sticky' => 'DESC'` will represent user role? I didn't knew we can get user role directly in orderby

Comment: Please read the note at the end of my answer.